# Swiss work permit regulations

Tags: resident-permit, job-hunting, switzerland

I am foreigner having a non-European Union citizenship and I own a swiss B permit coming from my previous job. There is no much time left till the end of the permit to find a new job in my profession. Currently I am looking for a job to prolong the permit to have enough time to find something in my field. My question is, will I be able to get a permit by being accepted to any job? What if I find part-time position or some low paid position? In these case will my permit be still prolonged? Is there any quota on given professions and/or foreigners?